# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: máximo de cursores abertos excedido

Tags: java, oracle, conexão

Estou com o seguinte erro:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: máximo de cursores abertos excedido

Pelo que eu pesquisei, o erro acontece quando é excedido numero máximo de cursores, e para solucionar, ou voce aumenta o número de cursores ou fecha as conexões, sendo que fechar as conexões seria a melhor opção. Minha aplicação é em `java` e ultilizado o padrão de `POJO` e `DAO` para fazer a conexão com o banco de dados oracle.

Minhas duas principais dúvidas são:

Se eu tenho que fechar os `PreparedStatement` dos métodos de incluir, alterar, excluir ou apenas do consultar (e no consultar fechar também o `ResultSet`) ?

Eu posso fechar fazendo desse jeito ?:

```
PreparedStatement ps = ConexaoOracle.getConexao().prepareStatement(SQL_CONSULTAR);
    ps.close();
```

Comment: Sim, o ideal é fechar tudo,principalmente o objeto de conexão que deve ser o que está causando a exceção.

Answer (score -2):

Sempre fechar o "result set" e o "prepared statement" com close():

sql = "select a,b,c,d from xpto;"

ps = conn.prepareStatemente(sql);

rs = ps.executeQuery();

...

rs.close();
ps.close();